Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.3.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources: - Gradle Core Plugins (plugin
I just created a new flutter project. Without modifying any thing, I tried to run the project in a physical device (SM N975F (mobile) • RF8M802FS2E • android-arm64  • Android 12 (API 31)), but I got Build failed with an exception error. I have be stuck here for a week now.
Below is the full error description:
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file '/Users/sule/Desktop/smcsw/android/settings.gradle' line: 21

* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.3.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Included Builds (None of the included builds contain this plugin)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:7.3.0')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Google
    MavenRepo
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                              4.4s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Below is the my flutter doctor detail:
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.2, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H2 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 3.22.2 on channel stable at /usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/3.22.2/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 761747bfc5 (6 weeks ago), 2024-06-05 22:15:13 +0200
    • Engine revision edd8546116
    • Dart version 3.4.3
    • DevTools version 2.34.3

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/sule/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+0-17.0.10b1087.21-11609105)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 11C505
    ✗ Flutter requires Xcode 14 or higher.
      Download the latest version or update via the Mac App Store.
    ! CocoaPods 1.11.3 out of date (1.13.0 is recommended).
        CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to
        your plugin usage on the Dart side.
        Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
        For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
      To upgrade see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#updating-cocoapods for
      instructions.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+0-17.0.10b1087.21-11609105)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.91.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.48.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • SM N975F (mobile) • RF8M802FS2E • android-arm64  • Android 12 (API 31)
    • macOS (desktop)   • macos       • darwin-x64     • Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H2 darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome      • web-javascript • Google Chrome 126.0.6478.127

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

Below is my Android/app/build.gradle:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    // The Flutter Gradle Plugin must be applied after the Android and Kotlin Gradle plugins.
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file("local.properties")
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty("flutter.versionCode")
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = "1"
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty("flutter.versionName")
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = "1.0"
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.smcsw"
    compileSdk = flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion = flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId = "com.example.smcsw"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdk = flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdk = flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode = flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName = flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source = "../.."
} 

Below is my Android/build.gradle:
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = "../build" 
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(":app")
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Below is my Android/settings.gradle:
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }()

    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.7.10" apply false
}

Below is my Android/gradle.properties:
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4G -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true

Below is my my gradle-wrapper.propertes:
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.3-all.zip

I have been stuck here for a week now. I have tried changing the builds, the distribution url and search endlessly online but no help. Please assist me.

You should update your Gradle file, since the version of the plugin (AGP
) and your gradle wrapper are not compatible as per this mapping
To make things easier for you to understand
Gradle is a build system
There's a gradle wrapper/executable that actually runs the gradle, and then there's the AGP, i.e. Android Gradle Plugin, that makes Android Development related tasks possible using the gradle build tool
Also, optionally
I don't think you should include the plugins block in the settings.gradle.kts file
As the name suggests, it should be the settings file, i.e. you could declare your plugin sources, and your repository sources here

I have done the update and also corrected plugin and gradle wrapper compatibility but I'm still have the same issue. I have used different network providers to be sure it's not my network, yet no result

I'm thinking that the artifacts were not downloaded during initial setup, but I don't know why. Not too sure as relatively new to flutter

Did you toggle Gradle Offline Mode

No, I didn't. I'm developing with vscode.
